# WP Rest API Returning All Custom Taxonomy Titles

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am using the WP REST API to return data from a custom post that has a custom taxonomy. This is my code -

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_book_type' );
function register_book_type() {
    register_rest_field( 'lesson',
        'book_type',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'get_book_type',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}
function get_book_type( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    $name = [];
    $object = get_terms(array(
      'taxonomy' => 'book_type'
    ));
    foreach ($object as $term) :
      array_push($name, $term->name.' ');
    endforeach;
    return implode('/ ', $name);
}
```

This returns all the taxonomy names, but I need it to return only the taxonomy names that apply to the specific post.

How can I change this so it only displays taxonomy names for the specific post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed $object = get_term to

```
 $object = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'book_type' );
```

and this pulls for the specific post